# Debug python module in another directory in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

I am trying to debug in Visual Studio Code a simple python program that imports a module from a different directory. It keeps giving me ModuleNotFoundError.

in /script/myProg.py, I am calling a function that resides in /lib/hello.py.
It runs fine but when I debug it, it raises exception.

Sorry I can't post images directly in the questions yet, but I have screen capped everything below:

[/script/myProg.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1G2MI.png)

[/lib/hello.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q00rg.png)

[launch.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DretQ.png)

[file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DECsd.png)

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mj1fi.png)

Comment: is the directory in the sys.path?

Comment: I think that's the reason - I added the current directory to sys.path and now it's working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I added the below code before the import and it's working.

import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'')